# InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid operator >= for PRIMARY KEY part "

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have a following dataset in cassandra :

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE userlog (
 term text,
 ts timestamp,
 year int,
 month int,
 day int,
 hour int,
 weekofyear int,
 dayofyear int,
 count counter,
 PRIMARY KEY (term, ts, year,month,day,hour,weekofyear,dayofyear)
);
```

.

```
term             | ts                       | year | month | day | hour | weekofyear | dayofyear | count
------------------+--------------------------+------+-------+-----+------+------------+-----------+-------
www.datastax.com | 2028-07-13 17:06:28+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:17:36+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     6
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:17:36+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:17:36+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:21:15+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:21:33+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:21:50+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:21:52+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www.datastax.com | 2015-07-28 16:21:53+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
             www | 2015-07-28 16:46:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
            www. | 2015-07-28 16:47:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
            www. | 2015-07-28 16:48:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
            www. | 2015-07-28 16:50:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
            www. | 2015-07-28 16:55:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
```

When I run this query :

```
SELECT * FROM userlog  WHERE ts >= '2015-07-28 16:46' AND  ts <= '2015-07-28 16:55' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

I get correct result :

```
term | ts                       | year | month | day | hour | weekofyear | dayofyear | count
------+--------------------------+------+-------+-----+------+------------+-----------+-------
www  | 2015-07-28 16:46:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www. | 2015-07-28 16:47:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www. | 2015-07-28 16:48:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www. | 2015-07-28 16:50:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
www. | 2015-07-28 16:55:00+0530 | 2015 |     7 |  28 |   16 |         31 |       209 |     2
```

but when I try to delete the rows with the same conditions

```
DELETE FROM userlog WHERE ts >= '2015-07-28 16:46' AND  ts <= '2015-07-28 16:55';
```

It throws following error :

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid operator >= for PRIMARY KEY part ts"
```

Am i missing something ? How to delete data in the specified time-range ? Also, is there any way to get the data in the specified time range (other than what I am doing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DELETE command does not support range queries or the ALLOW FILTERING clause.  From the documentation it only supports the = and IN operators:

You can delete an individual row by fully specifying both the partition and clustering columns.

You can delete a whole partition by just specifying the partition key.

And you can use the IN operator to do a few of these at once.

If you want to selectively delete rows from within a partition, you could first query for them using SELECT and then in your application issue a delete for each row returned from the SELECT.

Usually you wouldn't want to use ALLOW FILTERING on your SELECT statements since that is very inefficient, so normally you would specify the partition key when doing a range query SELECT.  You would structure your schema so that the information you need for an operation is in known partitions so that you wouldn't need to do a full table scan to find things.

Comment: `If you want to selectively delete rows from within a partition, you could first query for them using SELECT and then in your application issue a delete for each row returned from the SELECT.`

How to do this?How to pass the the select results to delete statements?

Comment: I am able to iterate and get results

`ResultSet result = session.execute(insertUpdateTable);
      
      while(result.iterator().hasNext())
      {
       System.out.println(result.one());
      }`

How to pass it to delete statement?

Comment: Great answer Jim!  There's a lot of confusion surrounding the CQL DELETE, so it's good to see it spelled-out like this.

Comment: @user-4870385 As you iterate through the resulting rows, you would use QueryBuilder to build the appropriate delete statement by reading the column values of each result row.  Then you would issue the delete statements asynchronously so that they would be pipelined to run quickly.